# CARTO dataset to connect the arcgis service

Tags: carto, arcgis-rest-api

I can not find the CARTO dataset to connect the arcgis service:
http://ags.cuzk.cz/arcgis/rest/services/ZABAGED_TOPO/MapServer/

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you send this query to CARTO Support email? Disclaimer: I work at CARTO.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, any layer from that ArcGIS map server is going to fail if the SR is not in `4326` (you can check the code [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/services/datasources/lib/datasources/url/arcgis.rb#L418)) when trying to connect with CARTO.

Comment: I dont think this is the case anymore. Take a look [here](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/a57bb6bae085c6bdf888b1b2104800d5fdd03eb8/services/datasources/lib/datasources/url/arcgis.rb#L461)